# xpath: if element contains more than 3 of these word, return element

Tags: php, regex, xpath

Actually I'm trying to retrive all html elements containing 3 or more words in my array list:

```
$xp= new DomXPath($myhtmlpage);
```

near by but wrong!

```
$xp->query("/* my xpath expression + content +regex + count condition */");
```

What's the way?

Comment: PHP uses libxml for XPath, which only supports XPath 1.0. This means for you: no support for regular expressions, bad string manipulation, ... Either fetch all elements and test them from PHP, or fetch another XPath engine supporting at least XPath 2.0. It would be as easy as `//*[count(tokenize(., ' ')[. = ('sequence', 'of', 'words', 'to', 'match')]) >= 3]` -- with a few more things to think of (how to split, whether to take content in subelements in account, ...). Have a look at Saxon, BaseX, ... -- there are lots of free implementations which are easy to setup and use and offer PHP APIs.

Comment: what about pear/XML_XPath2 ?

Comment: There is no code for that package, no releases, no documentation -- I guess it will never happen, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely fail-proof, but with XPath 1.0, there would be this rather ugly solution, here illustrated for matching `p` elements containing at least 3 words in sequence "cat", "apple", "tree", "bottle"

```
.//p[
        (
            number(contains(., "cat")) +
            number(contains(., "apple")) +
            number(contains(., "tree")) +
            number(contains(., "bottle"))
         ) >= 3
     ]
```

- `contains(., "word")` returning a boolean if context node contains desired word
- converting to 1/0 for true/false using `number()`
- summing that up with one expression per word
- and testing the minimal number of words you want

Comment: quite good, I agree with you and I know that the solution in 1.0 couldn't be so elegant, but this seems to be the right answer, what about performance? Do you think that is better to use this native solution or use a pear package with XPath 2.0 ?

Comment: Didn't think of that number-hack, +1 for that. :) This still has some issues with tokenization, think of "cat" and "at" (still not solved with my query in the comments above, but solvable using regular expressions for tokenization).

Comment: @Emergento, I have no experience in XPath in PHP, so I cannot comment on performance, but I guess this involves a lot of string conversion, substring matching, multiple times the same thing to recompute. I don't know if there are  optimizations for that in libxml. Indeed @JensErat, one could throw a bit of `contains(concat(' ', . , ' '), ' word ')` trick (as in class matching) into it and that would make an even scarier expression :)